# Merging results in an error (Error: cannot allocate vector)?

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-manipulation

I have two data frames df1 and df2 like below

**df1**

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

**df2**

| ID | CD |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |

I need to join these two data frames in a way that all matching 'ID' rows in df2 are brought into df1 with the column 'CD.' The expected merged data frame should look like this:

**df3**

| ID | CD |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | C |

I am trying left join in R (code below), but I end up having more rows than what is needed.

```
    df3 <- df1 |>
            left_join(df2, join_by(ID))
```

Comment: Two things wrong: (1) `join_by` (or `by=`) needs to be the field(s) in common between the two frames, not the columns you want to join ***IN*** to the first frame, so you need `join_by(ID)` instead. (2) Your second frame has many rows for each `ID`, so you will naturally get a one-to-many expansion on your join. Since they are invariant, you likely want `distinct(df2)`. Ultimately, `df1 |> left_join(distinct(df2), join_by(ID))`.

Comment: If my comment and the dupe-links don't resolve your question, Sai Paritala, please edit your question to include what you've tried since and why it is not correct. After that, please @-ping me and we'll work through the issue. Good luck!